# Can Google Chrome read/scan my ProtonMail inbox page?

Tags: encryption, web-browser, email, chrome, protonmail

If I used Google Chrome to visit **ProtonMail** website, it would not be difficult for Google to read my emails since it would just need to scan/read the content of the page. Messages are encrypted just on the servers, not on the browser. Should I then use Chrome or another browser to check my inbox?

Comment: Read this Reddit post: [Never connect to ProtonMail using Chrome](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProtonMail/comments/9yl94k/never_connect_to_protonmail_using_chrome/)

Comment: Browser plugins and/or extensions could technically at least scan the ProtonMail content you have on your screen. Also while not exactly what you are asking about but if you are in a setup like [these students in the Australian state of Victoria](https://www.itnews.com.au/news/victoria-installing-zscaler-on-students-personal-devices-to-monitor-traffic-577947), the ProtonMail contents you see on the screen can be scanned by a MitM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I then use Chrome or another browser to check my inbox?

The problem is probably less the browser since this browser is used by lots of others and such behavior might be detected. More of a problem are likely browser extensions you have installed, malware injected into the browser or any software which does SSL interception. SSL interception is done by various antivirus software, ad-injection software like [superfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfish) or by several corporate firewalls. It can also be done by malware.

Comment: Steffen has right you should be more worry about the extensions installed than the browser itself.

Answer (score 3):

If you're reading your mail in a browser, then the browser can read your mail. This means that Firefox or Google or Microsoft or Apple or Opera or whoever makes your browser can read your email.

But it's worth pointing out that Google is no more likely than any other browser maker to **want** to read your mail. They don't have a reason to. Plus, open source browsers are easy to audit, and even closed source browsers can be audited for unusual network activity, and people **do** check relatively often for other reasons. So we know with reasonable certainty that all the major browsers are clean.

There real concern if browser **plugins**, particularly those malicious plugins that may have been installed without your knowledge when you installed a hacked version of Photoshop or a keygen you downloaded from piratebay.

If you're going to be afraid of someone reading your mail, be afraid of the criminal actor who wants to scam your friends and family or who wants to raid your bank account. That stuff happens. But Google reading your mail off your browser screen? That *doesn't* happen.

Comment: "Google is no more likely than any other browser maker to want to read your mail. They don't have a reason to." - uh, advertising data?

Answer (score 1):

In theory yes. This could be possible for any company with any Browser they have code access to. They only need to send the response to their own servers.

However, I can not imagine this will be ever the case.

- It would be a huge scandal if that would be publicly and the user can easily recognize this by viewing the upload size. This would be the end for any Browser of this company.
- It costs a lot of bandwidth and computing capacity on google's site, to understand the data.

Comment: We know that Google processes Gmail emails so the computing power to scan all of proton mail must be trivial for them.